# Spring batch After Practitioner Reader not starting

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Our spring batch reader is not getting started if we partition the file path to bigger numbers

- Thread Pool Executer 30
- We are reading 5000 file path from DB in Partition and add in Execution Context.

```
    for (int i=0;i<rows.size();i++) {
                            String invoiceNumber = (String) rows.get(i).get("DOC_REFNUM");
                            fileName = ((String) rows.get(i).get("BI_REFERENCE")).trim();
                            billMedium = (String) rows.get(i).get("BI_MEDIUM_SHDES");
                            context.put("fileName", fileName);
                                context.put("DOC_REFNUM", invoiceNumber);
                                context.put("billMedium", billMedium);
                                map.put("Process"+i, context);
                                context = new ExecutionContext(); 
                           }
```

- Total 30 worker will start parallel(Thread Pool Executer)

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("masterStep")
    public Step masterStep() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner()).step(slaveStep())
                .gridSize(30).taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).listener(new InvoiceStepListener()).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

we have solved the issue by below flow

1. Currently we are getting XML filepath in a Table
2. Instead of Partition into larger chunks we partition based on Grid/Thread pool core size.
3. Each worker slave will get partitioned files and process one by one and commit chunk add additional performance again.

Please add if you are using any other better options.